# Best practices for weekly report emails with chart data as images

Tags: email, images

I am working on a project where I have an application that is generating a weekly report which is emailed to the user. The weekly report will contains various different charts. The charts are generated as a png, I was looking at base64 encoding the image and embedding the image into the email but found out that this isn't viable as most email clients don't support embedded images. Therefore was looking instead at having the image saved somewhere on my webserver and the email has an `img` tag which points to the URL of where the image is stored.

This means though that if anyone can determine the URL and the format, anyone can access the charts from someone else's account. There's no personal information in the charts so not sure if this is a big concern but wondering if there's any best practices or alternatives for doing what I am trying to achieve.